# Find the index of an NSString NSArray, matching a specific string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an array of NSString.

```
exampleArray = @[@"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19", @"20"];
```

Let's say you have..

```
NSString *exampleString = @"7";
```

I want to find exampleString, in exampleArray, and have it return the index of 2, the index where @"7" is located.

What is the best way to do this besides looping through and comparing isEqualToString?

Comment: Use `indexOfObject:` or `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` for more complex comparison

Comment: Much more detailed and comprehensive answer, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811121/check-if-nsstring-instance-is-contained-in-an-nsarray

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if([exampleArray containsObject:exampleString]) {
    int index = [exampleArray indexOfObject: exampleString];
} else {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```