# Finding match to a specific string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have some image files in the documents folder and the names look like a_b.png , where a is the ID (its a number) of each user and b is the name of the picture(s) he saves. So i want to find all the pictures of the user with e.g id=1 and save them to an array. Im going through each image file and i want to compare the name of the file with the pattern 1_*.png  . I tried

```
 NSString *searchterm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu_*.png",clientID];
 for(NSString filename in docFiles)
 {
 if([fileName isEqualTostring:searchterm])
 {.....}
 }
```

but i get no result.

Any ideas of how i can make that happen?

Comment: You use a Regex/NSPredicate

Comment: Can you print `filename` and `searchterm` for every loops ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing a string to an array in objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011996/comparing-a-string-to-an-array-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Create a sub-directory for each client ID, saving all images for that client within this sub-directory.
2. Use [`[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) to enumerate the files within that client sub-directory.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I ll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the prefix and suffix. I imagine this would be more efficient than regex anyway, and definitely easier to read.

```
 if([fileName hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_",clientID]] && [fileName hasSuffix:@".png") {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As large suggests to do the asterisk wildcarding you want, you should use NSPredicate to filter docFiles. For example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", searchterm];
NSArray *results = [docFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But trojanfoe's answer seems like a better practice in general.